# Is MATLAB the best coding tool for Digital Image Processing?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, opencv

I am a beginner. I do coding in Matlab only for image processing purpose. But my friends say it is very slow and in OpenCv I could get multiple times faster output results compared to Matlab.In basic reference book like DIP by Gonzalez and Woods ,they have used Matlab for programming.

So is Matlab the best coding tool for Digital Image Processing? 
What are the advantages and disadvantages of coding in  Matlab? Also,What are other good options by which we can do coding for image processing ?

Comment: MATLAB is only good for prototyping and learning DIP. C/C++ is a way to go when it comes to proper implementations. Checkout [**this answer**](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/16320/8202) for more details.

Comment: @jojek I am not so good in programming. could you discuss the simplicity factor about these languages. So which is simple to code and understand?

Comment: Don't know programming? Go for MATLAB then and meanwhile learn some Python or C++ to use OpenCV.

Comment: In my oppinion, Halcon from MVTec is the best image processing tool. It is simple to learn and fast. Also provides libraries for other programming languages. The con ist its price.